# Use different categories for a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I was wondering if it was possible not to mix the categories across my different custom post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean having different taxonomies for your custom post types? If so, you can define custom taxonomies and apply this taxonomies only to the post types you want. If the custom taxonomy has "hierarchical" argument set to true, the taxonomy will be works the same way categories do.

```
    register_taxonomy(
    'my_taxonomy_name',
    'my_custom_post_type',
     array(
                    'hierarchical' => true
    )
    );

      //And then
      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'my_taxonomy_name', 'my_custom_post_type' );
```

Comment: I absolutely didn't think about taxonomy, but yeah, that's it. Thanks :)

Comment: You are wellcome. Thinking in categories is thinking in taxonomies as, in wordpress, categories are a taxonomy built in the core; the same apply for the tags.